# DOM changes stop touch event listeners

Tags: reactjs, touch, ontouch

I have an issue with React touch events handlings that stop working when the DOM changes. I have a parent item with a `onTouchMove` handler. If I start my touch movement above this element and a child element that disappears during the touch movement my handler stops being called.

I reproduced there: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmRvmB?editors=0110#0

(To test touch events you need to use the responsive design mode and enable touch events in Chrome or Firefox)
The parent `div` (the green) has the `onTouchMove` handler, everything works fine if you start the touch outside of the blue child `div`, but if you start it in the blue `div`, when this one disappears (when your cursor `x` goes above a certain threshold in the code) the touch handler stops being called.

Here is the corresponding JS code reproducing this issue:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onTouchMove = this.onTouchMove.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      touchCurrentX: 0
    }
  }

  onTouchMove(ev) {
        console.log('onTouchMove');
        const x = ev.touches.item(0).screenX;
            this.setState({touchCurrentX: x});
  }

  render() {
    const child = this.state.touchCurrentX < 600 ? React.createElement('div', {key: 0, id: 'child'}, []) : null;
    const debug = React.createElement('span', {key: 1}, this.state.touchCurrentX);
    return React.createElement('div', {id: 'parent', onTouchMove: this.onTouchMove}, [child, debug]);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(TodoApp, {}, []), document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Is there a way to have my handler being still called even if children elements disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to let touch events fall through the children onto the parent. Simply add `style: { pointerEvents: "none" }` to child props or add it into your CSS. This is not a perfect solution, however. Some children may need their pointer events and IE may object to the CSS property.

Comment: That indeed fixes the issue! Apparently IE 11 is fine with this https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events. But it feels indeed hacky to have to change the style of all the children to have the touch working smoothly on the parent.